# Writing to file using data from variables

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random #  imports the random module

user_class = "" # Global variable
question_counter = int(0) # sets counter
amount_correct = int(0) # sets score



possible_operators = ("+","-","x") # creates a list of operators

while user_class == "": # Indefinite iteration - Runs until a valid class is given
    user_class = str(input("Please enter your class"))

    if user_class == "Rainbow": # Testing variable class - Will not crash the program
        class_file = open("RainbowClass.txt","a")

    elif user_class == "Sun":
        class_file = open("SunClass.text","a")

    elif user_class == "Moon":
        class_file = open("MoonClass.text","a")

    else:
        print("Not quite. Try again:")
        user_class = ""



name = str(input("Please enter your name"))


while question_counter < 10: # Indeffinate iteration – number of questions

    num1 = random.randint(1,10) # random number generation
    num2 = random.randint(1,10)
    operator = random.choice(possible_operators) # Chooses one of the operators from the list

    if operator == "+":
        answer = num1 + num2
    elif operator == "-":
        answer = num1 - num2
    elif operator == "x":
        answer = num1 * num2

    print("What is the answer to ", num1," "+operator+"" ,num2,"?")
    user_answer = int(input())


    if user_answer == answer:
        question_counter = question_counter + 1
        amount_correct = amount_correct + 1
        print("Correct!")

    else:
        print("Incorrect")
        question_counter = question_counter + 1


final_score = amount_correct
print("Well Done! You scored",amount_correct,"out of",question_counter,".")


amount_correct = str(amount_correct)
class_file.write(user_class)
class_file.write(name)
class_file.write(amount_correct + "\n")

class_file.close
```

This is my code. It does not get any errors when I run it but I am trying to get the user's class and open a text file according to the input. The file is opening but when it comes to the bottom it is not writing the data from the quiz that is inside the variables that I want it to.

What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested crack at this (sorry, Python is on another system). Ill break it up into chunks:

```
import random 

# Got rid of your global 'user_class'
# Moved the counter(s) to local function variables    
# Moved the operator options to local function variables
```

Now to tackle your first `while`, I would do:

```
def get_class_file():
    while True:
        # Don't need to call str(); input() returns a 'str'
        user_class = input("Please enter your class: ")

        if user_class == "Rainbow":
            class_file = "RainbowClass.txt"
            break
        elif user_class == "Sun":
            class_file = "SunClass.txt"
            break
        elif user_class == "Moon":
            class_file = "MoonClass.txt"
            break
        else:
            print("Not quite. Try again...")

    return class_file
```

Keep this:

```
# Don't need to call str(); input() returns a 'str'
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
```

Now for the second `while`, a similar function:

```
def get_score():
    # Don't need to call int()
    question_counter = 0  
    amount_correct = 0
    # Make this a tuple sequence; they are immutable
    possible_operators = ("+","-","x",)

    while True:
        if question_counter < 10:
            num1 = random.randint(1,10) # random number generation
            num2 = random.randint(1,10) 
            operator = random.choice(possible_operators)

            if operator == "+":
                answer = num1 + num2
            elif operator == "-":
                answer = num1 - num2
            elif operator == "x":
                answer = num1 * num2

            user_answer = int(input("What is the answer to: " 
                                    + str(num1) + operator + str(num2) + "?\n"))

            # Take out of the if/else since we always increment
            question_counter += 1

            if user_answer == answer:
                amount_correct += 1
                print("Correct!")
            else:
                print("Incorrect!")

        else:
            break

    return amount_correct
```

Lets put it all together, and see how we get the variables and then how to write them to your files:

```
import random 

def get_class_file():
    while True:
        # Don't need to call str(); input() returns a 'str'
        user_class = input("Please enter your class: ")

        if user_class == "Rainbow":
            class_file = "RainbowClass.txt"
            break
        elif user_class == "Sun":
            class_file = "SunClass.txt"
            break
        elif user_class == "Moon":
            class_file = "MoonClass.txt"
            break
        else:
            print("Not quite. Try again...")

    return class_file, user_class


def get_score():
    # Don't need to call int()
    question_counter = 0  
    amount_correct = 0
    # Make this a tuple sequence; they are immutable
    possible_operators = ("+","-","x",)

    while True:
        if question_counter < 10:
            num1 = random.randint(1,10) # random number generation
            num2 = random.randint(1,10) 
            operator = random.choice(possible_operators)

            if operator == "+":
                answer = num1 + num2
            elif operator == "-":
                answer = num1 - num2
            elif operator == "x":
                answer = num1 * num2

            user_answer = int(input("What is the answer to: " 
                                    + str(num1) + operator + str(num2) + "?\n"))

            # Take out of the if/else since we always increment
            question_counter += 1

            if user_answer == answer:
                amount_correct += 1
                print("Correct!")
            else:
                print("Incorrect!")

        else:
            break

    return amount_correct, question_counter

class_file, user_class = get_class_file()
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
final_score, num_asked = get_score()  


print("Well Done!\n" 
      "You scored " + str(final_score) + " out of " + str(num_asked) + ".")

# In all methods you called 'a' mode so set that here
# Using 'with open()' automatically closes the file after completion
with open(class_file, 'a') as f:
    f.write(user_class + "\n")
    f.write(name + "\n")
    f.write(str(final_score) + "\n")
```

Let me know if anything comes up, errors and such. Again, wasn't able to test.

Comment: Hey pstatix, thanks for your answer. Everything worked well until line 74, this statement:f.write(final_score + "\n")
. It returns a traceback error. This is what the shell says: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//fileserver/students/11197/GCSE CS Assessment summer/Task 2/Stack Overflow answer.py", line 73, in <module>
    f.write(final_score + "\n")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
>>>

Comment: FIXED: 'f.write(str(final_score) + "\n")' ... Thank you @pstatix

Comment: @BenColmer Sorry, all that to fail on something simple! I've updated it to include that fix as well. Again, I couldnt test when I was writing it. The question remains however, do you understand what was done? Please select as answer if you do and it works for you!

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you have done... Basically defined them as two different functions and called upon them later on... Meaning you can pass only one piece of data to write() at a time.. Selected it as answer :), Thanks again, @pstatix !